# MissingServletRequestPartException: Required request part 'file' is not present]

Tags: java, spring, api

i am facing with problem:

```
   Resolved [org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException: Required request part 'file' is not present]
```

What can I do to resolve it?

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/documents")
public class DocumentController {
private final DocumentService documentService;

@Value("${app.upload.dir:${user.home}}")
public String uploadDir;

public DocumentController(DocumentService documentService) {
    this.documentService = documentService;
}

@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<DocumentCreateResponse> addDocument(@RequestParam("") MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
    Path copyLocation = Paths
            .get(uploadDir + File.separator + StringUtils.cleanPath(file.getOriginalFilename()));
    Files.copy(file.getInputStream(), copyLocation, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);

    Document savedDocument = documentService.save(file.getResource().getFile());
    if (savedDocument == null) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(new DocumentCreateResponse(null), null, HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE);
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<>(new DocumentCreateResponse(savedDocument.getId()), null, HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
}
```

}

I send my postman message without header, and with selected option form-data file.
Should I configure something?

EDIT, after adding param "file" to @RequestParam and sending properly formatted request like this:

[image]

I get this error:
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception

```
 java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /user.home /file_example_XLS_10.xls
```

how should I change my directory? I think it is caused by uploadDir? Should I add something to my application.properties? I added this:

```
  app.upload.dir=//user.home
```

Comment: The parameter isn't there, regardless what you think it simply isn't available. So without seeing what you actually post this is going to be impossible to answer.

Comment: added parameter file, right now after posting request i get "No such file exceptio"

Comment: `file.getResource.getFile` will simply not work. You cannot resolve it to a `File` as it isn't a physical file. you would need to obtain the actually saved file.

Comment: how should i change that?

Comment: You copy the file to somewhere, you should use that.